# Update Trigger MSSQL - SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

On update of table in MSSQL i want to perform a certain task.

Now i have update trigger in place for the required table and my task(script) runs when a record is updated.

Now when user saves an existing record from web, my update trigger executes the task i have written. But when the user saves from the web page without modifying any record that time the update trigger would not work, as no records are modified.

I would want to trigger my script even if no record is modified. How can i do it?

Comment: Your script could possibly be an SP and either used in the trigger or called from code

Comment: It is a SP, and i am calling it in the trigger. Calling from code is not an option. 

But the trigger would not fire in case record is not changed.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "*record is not changed*"? If your application does send an `UPDATE` statement, the trigger will be fired even if the update sets the columns to the same value as before. If your application is **not** sending an `UPDATE` to the database, (because the user didn't change anything) then there is no way the trigger can be fired.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name - Buddy, update statement is sent to the database, it is a LINQ query. But because of the fact that no records are modified, the trigger is never invoked. According to you it should, but i checked it, it dosent buddy.

Comment: Then the `UPDATE` contains a `where` clause that results in updating zero rows.

Comment: No, the where clause is proper. If a record is modified, trigger is fired, but if nothing is modified and saved, update query is fired but trigger is not fired.

Comment: The trigger will alter some other table values.
The fact that the values have not change in the original table where the trigger is, SQL does not rewrite the values as they are same and update trigger is never fired. But irrespective of whether the values have changed or not i want to perform a certain task of updating other table, which is done in the update trigger which does not fire. Its like infinite loop of the problem
calling the SP or the script after the update statment from UI is not an option btw
i want to do it using triggers only

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to use a INSTEAD OF UPDATE trigger. By default triggers AFTER UPDATE.
But then you have to set the update statement inside the trigger. For more information,

[INSTEAD OF UPDATE Triggers.](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188601.aspx)

Comment: This does not help sorry.

The trigger will alter some other table values.
The fact that the values have not change in the original table where the trigger is, SQL does not rewrite the values as they are same and update trigger is never fired. But irrespective of whether the values have changed or not i want to perform a certain task of updating other table, which is done in the update trigger which does not fire. Its like infinite loop of the problem
calling the SP or the script after the update statment from UI is not an option btw
i want to do it using triggers only

Comment: I will mark this as answer because of different reasons. Solution to my problem was a new table, which will be holding values of the 2nd table using trigger on 2nd table.
Then use sql job to periodically check the new table entries and work with it and delete them in the end.